# Angular module from Github, how to integrate in my module?

Tags: angular, angular8

**Summary**

I'm looking for instructions on how to get a github-fork of a node_module integrated into my project, so I can use the module with my own modifications to it, without touching code inside node_modules/xyz.

**Details / example / reason:**

As an example I have found that angular/cdk drag and drop is quite nice, but has flaws. So I needed to change the code in node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm2015/drag-drop.js (which I don't want to).
But also plotly (https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js).

Mostly, like with the cdk/drag-drop there's a github repository with source code. And of course, changing sth. inside node_modules is ultra stupid and obviously I'd prefer to fork the repository instead and then link my fork in the package.json or so (?!).

That said...
I don't know how right now.
I could not find any docs or blogs on this topic. I guess I must be choosing the wrong keywords ??!

**What I'd like to ask for**

Could someone please give a link to a page that explains this process in great detail or at least summarize the important steps ?

What's on my mind so far...
Where to put the repository relative to my project, can/must it be in a parallel folder ?
In my main project how to link that new forked git module (is it in package.json ?)
Do I need to separately precompile that forked git module after every change ? Which commands ? Or is there an option so that my main module/project compiles each change through the ng serve watch as well on development ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options to use a dependency's fork in your Angular project:

## If your fork is only available locally

Please check [@Dino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57688566/2764486).

## Upload your fork on GitHub (or another Git host)

- in your `package.json`, import the fork like that: `"dependency": "git+https://github.com/your-username/your-git-repository.git"`
- your fork will be added to the `node_modules`directory
- be aware that you'll have to push all changes in your fork and execute `npm i` in your project again

To learn in detail how to import a GitHub repository as dependency, read also [the official npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).

## Upload your fork on npm

- [sign up](https://www.npmjs.com/signup) at npm to create an account
- go to your fork directory: `cd fork-directory`
- login to npm: `npm login`
- initialize your package: `npm init`

  - check that your package name does not exist yet: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/your-package-name` should return a 404 error
- publish your package: `npm publish`
- in your `package.json`, import the fork: `"your-package-name": "package-version"` (`package-version` is the version number of your npm package)
- be aware that each time you have changes in your fork, you'll have to publish a **new package version with higher package version number than before** and execute `npm i` in your project again

To learn how to publish an npm package, read also [this blog post](https://zellwk.com/blog/publish-to-npm/) and [the official npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish).

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I push a new commit to my fork and call npm i again,I don't get the latest update. Only if I use a new Version number like "plotly.js": "git+https://github.com/Allisone/plotly.js.git#v1.49.5". Can I tell him to always pull the latest changes ?

Comment: If you push your commits to the master branch, it should actually retrieve the latest version. Otherwise remove the fork package from your `node_modules` directory and try `npm i` again. Now it must be re-downloaded because your removed it before.

Comment: yes of course deleting and rerunning npm i works, but he doesn't seem to go for newest HEAD revision otherwise. maybe someone will know a trick ...

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite simple.

Fork the `@angular/cdk` and place it `/root/projects` (or make your own naming).

Now in your `app.module.ts` or which ever module you will use, you will have to import the `DragDropModule` from `/root/projects`, and not from `node_modules` as you would normally do.

```
import {DragDropModule} from 'projects/cdk-fork/drag-drop';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    DragDropModule
    ....
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

You can apply that approach to any module you wish to fork and edit.